# Which version of Angular/AngularJS does CiviCRM use?

Tags: developer, angular

I'm working on learning Angular/AngularJS for use with CiviCRM and confused about which version I should be learning. How can I see which version CiviCRM is using?

Answer (score 3):

#### How to check your Angular version

1. Go to the default Angular *base page* for your site at `http://example.org/civicrm/a`
2. Open a browser console
3. Evaluate `angular.version` within the console:

   [image: screenshot]

#### Notes about Angular versions

- 1.x is called "AngularJS" and has documentation at [docs.angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org)
- 2.x (onwards) is called "Angular", has [significant changes](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference) from 1.x, and has documentation at [angular.io/docs](https://angular.io/docs/)
- CiviCRM (as of version 4.7.x) use AngularJS 1.x
- Within AngularJS 1.x there are [some changes between minor versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Answer (score 2):

With even version 5 of civicrm it is still using angular 1.5. I checked it on the demo site https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk/civicrm/a

on the console i ran:

> angular.version, and it returned this :-
>   {full: "1.5.11", major: 1, minor: 5, dot: 11, codeName: "princely-quest"}